# MYSQL , PHP , SELECT where to do

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, where-clause

How to select rows with  `id` from `5` to `10` ? My query :

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = '5' do `id` = '10'");
```

Comment: Robert has already answered. Just note that it includes 5 and 10 also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` between '5' and '10'");
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can achieve it using logical operator `AND` and comparison operators `>=` and `<=` if you want to include `5` and `10`, otherwise use `>` and `<`:

```
 mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` >= 5 and `id` <= 10 ");
```

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is fair, you are looking for

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE 1 LIMIT 5,10);
```